# My session variables lose their values after a certain length of time, can I lengthen the period somehow?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, session-variables

My session variables hold the values that the users use to log in but they seem to initialise after five minutes or so if the website isn't used. Is there any way I can lengthen this period as the system logs the user out if the log in details are not there?

Comment: Well, that's what a session is designed for : )

Comment: I would resist increasing the session timeout value, and instead implement an AJAX "keep alive", as nunespascal suggests in his answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the session timeout in web.config;

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can I put it anywhere in web.config or does it need to go in a particular section? Ignore this, I found out it goes under system.web. Thanks again that should do the trick.

Comment: @user616076 Updated with location

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the IIS timeout by

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

Usually have a very long session is not a good idea. It increases the load on your server.

Consider using an AJAX call to send a heart-beat message to the server to tell it to keep the session alive.

That way you can keep a small timeout on the server, but a much longer one for clients who are having the application open in the browser.

Comment: I would also recommend the AJAX based "keep alive" method